# Powershell search text for the value "1"

Tags: powershell, pattern-matching

Please could someone give me a hand I'm sort of new to powershell so your patience and knowledge would very much be appreciated.

Here's the problem: I have txt file with numbers on each line.
I need to Parse the txt file and find out how many times a specific value occurs
so in the example below I need to search the file for the value then count the number of occurrences

Example:

```
12,
2,
41,
234,
21,
1,
11,
1,
```

This is what I have tried so far

```
$txt = get-content 'C:\numbers.txt'
$search = $txt -match "1"
$search.count
```

But the results also find 12, 41, 21, 1, 11
How do I find out how to find the count of just 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can split each line then use the -like operator instead of -match, with -like,both sides of the expression have to be the same, (but you can still use the usual wildcards * and ? ) :

```
(gc c:\temp\tsts.txt |%{  $_.split(', ') -like 1 }|Measure-Object).count
```

Comment: Thank you Kayasax, your example works but I am still trying to understand why it works? What does splitting the strings accomplish how does this make a difference?

Comment: using get-content, you got an array of stings  (filled with the lines of your file). 
as i told you -like return true if both side are equals, so you've got to split this line into individual characters to compare to '1'
`PS>"12, 2, 41, 234, 21, 1, 11, 1,222" -like 1` => false